# java numeros grandes obtenidos del factorial de 17 en adelante

Tags: java, math

Estoy trabajando con factoriales y en la salida no estoy obteniendo datos precisos en el factorial de 17 en adelante:

> El factorial de 17 es -288522240,    El factorial de 18 es -898433024,
>   El factorial de 19 es 109641728,    El factorial de 20 es -2102132736,
>   El factorial de 21 es -1195114496, etc.

Mi código es el siguiente:

// Con este método encuentro el factorial

```
static int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

//Dentro del main así es como estoy llamando al método:

```
for(aux=rangoInf+1; aux<=rangoSup; aux++){
    System.out.println("El factorial de "+ aux+" es "+ factorial(aux) );
    //suma=suma+factorial(aux);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema se debe al tipo de dato que se encuentra almacenado el factorial, como se sabe el tipo de dato `int` posee un valor máximo de `2,147,483,647` y un valor mínimo de `-2,147,483,648` por lo tanto habrá un desbordamiento de datos ya que se estaría multiplicando valores muy grande y que el dato de tipo `int` no lo pueda soportar y que nunca supere esa barrera establecida quedándose estancado sin mostrar el verdadero valor del factorial X, se podría decir que usará la variable de tipo `long` pero ¡Pam! Otro problema similar y es que ese tipo de dato también posee un limite con un máximo de `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` y un mínimo de `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` sin mostrar de nuevo el verdadero del factorial buscado. Yo te recomendaría usar la clase `java.math.BigInteger` que puede ayudarte en resolver ese problema sin tener un limite establecido como los otros dos anteriores, por lo tanto el método de obtener el factorial de X número quedaría como:

```
static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    if (n == null) // si la variable es nula, ya que no queremos errores de tipo NPE
        return null;
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) // si ya llego a cero como en el anterior código que regrese uno
        return BigInteger.ONE;

    /* La clase BigInteger posee un método donde puede
     * multiplicar con otro BigInteger así podemos aprovechar
     * eso, también otro método para restar para poder hacer
     * el método de cómo debería buscar el factorial de X
     * número como en el código anterior
     */
    return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     /* Como se puede se podrá ver, para poder crear
      * una instancia de BigInteger podemos crearlo con
      * con un String con el número que queramos, y para
      * poder obtener el número y que se muestre con el valor
      * obtenido del método que devolvería un número grande
      * se usaría el toString() que devolvería claramente un
      * String
      */
    BigInteger aux = new BigInteger("19");
    System.out.println("El factorial de " + aux.toString() + " es de " + factorial(aux).toString());
}
```

También en la clase `java.math.BigInteger` hay tres contantes que son `BigInteger.ZERO` que representaría el valor de `0`, `BigInteger.ONE` que representaría el valor de `1` y el `BigInteger.TEN` que representaría el valor de `10`, por lo tanto se podría usar en el método.

Espero haberte ayudado. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Funciono muy bien!, mil gracias Poku.