# Problema para calcular el factorial en Python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en la programación e intentando hacer un programa para calcular el factorial de un número me encontré con un problema, y es que no calcula correctamente los factoriales a partir del 12, y no sé a que se puede deber.

He encontrado un post similar pero no estoy seguro si está relacionado con mi problema, además de que es en java: [java numeros grandes obtenidos del factorial de 17 en adelante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262853/java-numeros-grandes-obtenidos-del-factorial-de-17-en-adelante)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np


def factorial(integer):
    if integer == 0:
        return 1
    elif integer < 0:
        return 'The integer must be a positive number'
    elif integer > 0:
        lower_numbers = []
        while integer > 0:
            lower_numbers.append(integer)
            integer -= 1
        return np.prod(lower_numbers)


print(factorial(int(input())))
```

(Ya sé que hay maneras mucho más eficientes de calcular la integral, pero como he dicho soy nuevo y esta fue la forma más lógica que se me ocurrió)

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que los enteros en NumPy (y el resto de tipos nativos) tienen un tamaño fijo y limitado en general dependiente de la plataforma heredados de C. Lo máximo que puedes hacer en principio con NumPy estándar es usar `numpy.uint64`, que te abarca desde 0 hasta 18446744073709551615, es decir el factorial de 20 a lo sumo.

Dado que solo usas NumPy para el producto, lo más simple es que dejes de usarlo y uses `math.prod` de la stdlib. El tipo `int` en Python tiene teóricamente una precisión ilimitada.

```
import math


def factorial(integer):
    if integer == 0:
        return 1
    elif integer < 0:
        return 'The integer must be a positive number'
    elif integer > 0:
        lower_numbers = []
        while integer > 0:
            lower_numbers.append(integer)
            integer -= 1
        return math.prod(lower_numbers)
```

**`math.prod` se ha añadido en Python 3.8**, en versiones anteriores podemos usar `functools.reduce` junto a `operator.mul` por ejemplo:

```
import functools
import operator


def factorial(integer):
    if integer == 0:
        return 1
    elif integer < 0:
        return 'The integer must be a positive number'
    elif integer > 0:
        lower_numbers = []
        while integer > 0:
            lower_numbers.append(integer)
            integer -= 1
        return functools.reduce(operator.mul, lower_numbers, 1)
```

Ejemplo de salida:

> ```
> 50
> 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
> ```

Ésto sin modificar tu idea original, pero ten en cuenta que la creación de la lista es tremendamente ineficiente e innecesaria.

```
import math


def factorial(integer):
    if integer == 0:
        return 1
    elif integer < 0:
        return 'The integer must be a positive number'
    elif integer > 0:
        return math.prod(range(2, integer + 1))
```

O un simple `for` sin depender de librería externas:

```
def factorial(integer):
    if integer < 0:
        return 'The integer must be a positive number'
    else:
        prod = 1
        for n in range(2, integer + 1):
           prod *= n
        return prod
```